# Pandas: Incorrect rows returned when retrieving data based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to retrieve the rows in my dataframe that **do not** equal 100 when col_1 + col_2 + col_3 are added together using the following code below:

```
df.loc[(df["col_1"] + df["col_2"] + df["col_3"]).ne(100)]
```

However, when executing the code to retrieve these rows, I am getting rows that **are** equal to 100 when these three columns are added together, including the rows that do not equal 100 too. Hence, I am **only** after the rows that do not equal 100 when these columns are added together.

For example, check out the sample below.

When the code is executed this is what I am getting. As you can see, the first row adds up to 80, the second row adds up 90, and the last three add up to 100. Therefore, the last three rows should not be there, as I **only** want the rows that **do not** equal 100 when these three columns are added together.

Any help on how to achieve this would be very helpful. Maybe something is wrong with the code I am using?

Thanks!

```
---------------------------------
ID     col_1     col_2     col_3
---------------------------------
1      50        10        20
---------------------------------
2      30        20        40
---------------------------------
3      40        50        10
---------------------------------
4      10        90        0
---------------------------------
5      70        20        10
---------------------------------
```

Comment: I'm not sure where your problem lies. Running the line of code you shared on the provided data frame, the result returns only the 2 expected rows.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But, I only want the output to return the 2 expected rows only, not anything that is equal to 100. :)

Comment: Your code works as intended. Rows `ID 1` and `ID 2` are returned.

Comment: Thanks - but why is it returning rows that are equal to 100?

Comment: It does not return rows that are equal to 100 with your example code with your example data. Please try your code with the data you provided for yourself.

Comment: But why are rows ID3, ID4 and ID5 returned?

Comment: 20 bucks the ints are strings, verifiable with `df.info()`. If "Object" is the data type, then you need to convert the columns to int with `df["col_1"] = df["col_1"].astype(int)` and repeat for int columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's load your data into a frame:

```
import pandas as pd

# Not the best way, but it's sufficient
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["col_1"] = [50, 10, 40, 10, 70]
df["col_2"] = [10, 20, 50, 90, 20]
df["col_3"] = [20, 40, 10, 0, 10]


# Now retrieve only rows not summing to 100 (NOTE: This is your code)
df.loc[(df["col_1"] + df["col_2"] + df["col_3"]).ne(100)]
```

**OUTPUT**

|  | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 50 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 40 |

This is exactly what you are expecting, and your code line achieves it. For validation's sake:

Pandas version: 1.0.5

#### **Update after comment from [@David Erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6366770/david-erickson)**

If your DataFrame values are strings, all the rows will be returned by your query. If you know that all columns need to be integers, you can do the following:

```
df = df.astype("int")
```

However, if there are other columns that you don't want to affect, then you can individually change the type of a column:

```
df["col_1"] = df["col_1"].astype("int")
```

To check that your columns are the data type you expect, execute

```
df.info()
```

After verifying your columns are integers, your provided query will execute with the expected result.

Comment: I understand what you are saying: my code does work. But, when I execute it, it is returning 5 rows - not 2! That is what is confusing me. Your output is correct, I know. Though, when I execute it myself, the output includes the values that equal 100.

Comment: Then I suggest carefully comparing versions and the sample line you provided in your question. Something in what you are executing locally and what you are providing here is different. I can only provide answers based on information I have, and with what I have available, there is no issue with your code.

Comment: @AnandP2812 are your integers strings? Use `df["col_1"] = df["col_1"].astype(int)` and do that for all `int` columns. You can verify your data types with `df.info()`.

Comment: @DavidErickson I updated my answer supporting that case. If the columns were all strings, they would all return. I don't know why I didn't consider that originally. Good catch!

Comment: Hi - thanks for the update. My values are `float64`.

Comment: In this case, floats should act the same as integers. Confirmed on my Google Colab instance.